# shell script not working

Tags: ssh, ksh, remote-access

I have a shell script to do the following things

1. sudo as a user (johnsmith) and perform few things
2. Exit from that user and check url status
3. If status is not equal to 1 , ssh to one more server and execute a
   script.

But when I am running it, the lines inside `'ENDBASH'` are not getting executed at all.

```
     #!/bin/ksh
     echo "Outside ENDBASH ${@##*/}"

    sudo -u johnssmith bash <<'ENDBASH'  

    echo "Inside ENDBASH ${@##*/}"

    #Obtaining the new version file
    for file in "${@##*/}"
     do
     if echo "$file" | grep -E "abc_cde_efg"; then
         echo "Version found: $file"
    else
           echo "Version not found"
    fi
    done        
    exit
ENDBASH

urlArray=('http://server:port/servicename1/services/servicename1?wsdl' 'http://server:port/servicename2/services/servicename2?wsdl')

status=0
    for url in "${urlArray[@]}"
     do
       result=`curl -s $url`

        if (echo $result | grep '<?xml' >/dev/null 2>&1); then
           service=$(echo $url | cut -d"/" -f4)
           echo "$service is Running"
      else
           service=$(echo $url | cut -d"/" -f4)
          echo "$service is not Running"
         status=1
        fi
     done    
if [ $status != 1 ] ; then
 ssh -t username@hostname /home/dev_was/test1.sh 
fi
```

Comment: did you turn on `set -vx` to debug your script? And you know that using `... <<'ENDBASH'` (quoted) will not expand any variables from the current shell into that Here-document? To test that here-doc is working as intended, you could replace `ssh ....` with `cat - <<'HERDOC'`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : I didn't get your explanation. But I found out that the arguments I am passing to run the script are not going inside `<<'ENDBASH'`. I have modified my above code with 2 echo statements `Inside ENDSSH` and `Outside ENDSSH`. there are no values for `Inside ENDSSH` . How can pass my arguments inside as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly pass the arguments received by your script to the internal script:

```
sudo -u johnssmith bash -s "$@" <<'ENDBASH'
```

Comment: It worked.. But I want to pass the same arguements to another script test1.sh in the line `ssh -t username@hostname /home/dev_was/test1.sh`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The naive approach of `ssh -t ... /home/dev_was/test1.sh "$@"` should work as long as the arguments don't contain any white space. If they do, you might need to do something more complex.